# Flask can't route to certain url with blueprint

Tags: python, flask, blueprint

I am trying to organize my flask project, but there's something wrong.
I have this directory:

```
app/ 
    __init__.py
    views/
        pages.py
```

On my `__init__.py` file I've imported the `pages` object and 
registered it as a blue print.

This is the code on my `pages.py` file.

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

pages = Blueprint('pages', __name__) #no prefix

@pages.route('/')
def index():
    return '<h1>in index.html</h1>'

@pages.route('/home')
def home():
    return '<h1>in home.html</h1>'
```

If I run the flask app, open the browser, and go to `localhost:5000`,
I will see the headline 'in index.html'.
But if I go to `localhost:5000/home`, I will get the message `404 Not Found message`.

Does anyone know the reason for this behavior?

Comment: You have two return statements on last line

Comment: I believe you should register it as a blueprint:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/blueprints/#registering-blueprints

Comment: @FábioCorreia I thank you for trying to help, really. but as i said, i had registered pages as blueprint. and if i hadn't the index page wouldn't load either.

Comment: Got it! I am trying to reproduce your error here, I will update if I find anything more.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first the folder structure:

```
app/
  __init__.py
  main.py

  views/
  __init__.py
  test.py
```

Contents of main.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from views.test import pages

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(pages) <-- blueprint registration
```

Contents of test.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint

pages = Blueprint('pages', __name__) #no prefix


@pages.route('/')
def index():
    return '<h1>in index.html</h1>'


@pages.route('/home')
def home():
    return '<h1>in home.html</h1>'
```

I believe the **register_blueprint** was the only thing missing.

Comment: Thank you for the devotion. but as i said, i did register the blue print. When I'll find the answer I could update you if you're interested.

Comment: I don't know if you posted all your folder structure and code with "main" flask, if you could update it, I would be glad to continue helping you.

Comment: No changes made, just turn all off and restart computer. Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

When stuff like that happen, just turn off everything, reset your computer.

Sometimes the bug is not yours.